# Using rust+webassembly for web development, how to solve the extra cost of wasm and js interaction

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

I am currently trying to develop a part of a web application using Rust compiled into a wasm part (there are similar frameworks such as yew, etc.), but I find that using webassembly may have more consumption, for example, I have to do a click button call a JS function. The JS function performs some calculations（very simple calculation） and presents the results to dom

Use only js's solution:

- JS calls another JS function
- Another JS function performs some calculations and directly renders the results through some of the document's APIs.

The solution for using Rust + Webassembly:

- JS calls a wasm function
- Wasm performs some calculations. After the calculation, the result is encoded into a TypedArray, and the JS function is called to render the dom.
- JS decodes the corresponding content in the TypeArray and then renders the dom to screen.

Here we do not consider using React or Vue, just using WebAssembly may reduce performance, which is mainly reflected in:

- More function calls
- Added the encode/decode procedure and possible memory copies.

The advantage of Webassembly may be that the calculation is faster, but this advantage is likely to not save the overall time due to the increased overhead mentioned above, and it is obviously slow when it comes to DOM operations.

But I still did a comparison test for DOM operations:

JS creates 10,000 p-tags and takes about 120ms:

```
function web_bench() {
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  let begin = Date.now();
  for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
    let str = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "123456789012345678901234567890123456abcd123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678哈哈1234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789哈哈2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123嘻嘻67890123456789012345678901234567890" +
      "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234哈哈哈012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

    let p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = str;
    container.appendChild(p);
  }
  let time = Date.now() - begin;
  console.log('cost time:', time);
}
```

If I use rust: cost 180ms

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn bench() {
    let document = web_sys::window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
    for i in 0..10000 {
        let str = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456abcd1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678哈哈123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789哈哈234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678902345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123嘻嘻6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234哈哈哈012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
        let p = document
          .create_element("p")
          .unwrap();
        p.set_inner_html(str);
        document
          .get_element_by_id("container")
          .unwrap()
          .append_child(&p);
    }
}
```

Does this mean that rust+wasm is not suitable for web development that interacts frequently with dom operations, and is only suitable for computing modules. How does the current Rust web framework think this problem? Is my analysis correct?

Thanks for your opinion~

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things that add overhead to JS <=> WebAssembly calls, and impact performance:

1. There is quite a bit of overhead involved in communicating between WebAssembly and JavaScript, involving a process called trampolining via C++ code.
2. In order to exchange data (other than simple numbers), the values need to be encoded / decoded via linear memory.

Both of these contribute to a measurable overhead on a per-function call basis.

However, things are improving ...

1. Browser vendors are [looking to remove the trampolining](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/10/calls-between-javascript-and-webassembly-are-finally-fast-%F0%9F%8E%89/).
2. Via the [interface types](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/10/calls-between-javascript-and-webassembly-are-finally-fast-%F0%9F%8E%89/) proposal, the encode / decode overhead will be significantly reduced.

WebAssembly is a very new technology, it takes time to optimise and resolve performance issues.

> Does this mean that rust+wasm is not suitable for web development that interacts frequently with dom operations

At the moment, potentially yes. In the future, this will likely be viable

> Is my analysis correct?

Your current observation, that it is a bit slow at the moment is correct.